# Using OpenStreetMap on iPhone offline

Tags: iphone, xcode, openstreetmap

I am working on an iPhone app. project and my group is trying to use the OpenStreetMap offline. 
I have been Googling for tutorials but can't find any decent tutorials. Can any of you guys help me out and give me a link for good tutorial?

We need to be able to access the map offline. Right now I have downloaded the map image tiles for my city and put it into the database file and it runs on the iPhone simulator but I want to be able to "limit" the user view because you could scroll out of bounds and you can see the grey area where no tiles were downloaded.
Other features I need to know how to edit is adding a marker (for example, I want to include a bus stop on the map when you open the app on iPhone)

Any help would be appreciated guys
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I build an app which also uses OpenStreetMap. I used route-me library for it. By default, if you do no configuration, it fetches its tiles from the internet and then caches the most recently retrieved tiles in a database in your documents directory.

The code is readable and not too big. I had to draw to layers instead of one, so i overrode some classes (TileSource and Tile) and got it working with two layers.

I don't think it would be hard to adjust the tilecache to keep its contents permanently offline and to limit it to a specific area. By the way, route-me also knows some db formats as tile source. But I've never used them.

The wiki documentation on the github site tells you how to include route-me in your own project. I used the external link that pointed to how to do it in Xcode 4.

https://github.com/route-me/route-me